# Switch logarithm mode off MS Chart

Tags: c#, mschart

I have switch logarithm mode on, but now i want to switch it off to see the original graph but i am not able to do so. I am using the below code but it does not bring the axis back to its original position/values

chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = false;

Comment: Given your names are correct it should. If it doesn't there must be code that prevents or 'resets' again. Note: Logarithmic is __not the default__ as your question implies! If you see logarithm mode at all you must be turning it __on__ somewhere.

Comment: Yes i am switching it on. But after switching it on, i want to switch it off also to see the original graph.

Comment: Have you tried `chart.Refresh()` after changing the property to false? You may need to redraw the chart.

Comment: I can put this `chart1.ChartAreas["A01"].AxisX.IsLogarithmic = checkBox1.Checked;` in a checkBox1_CheckedChanged event and it works fine. (No need to refresh either.) Have you looked for _Logarithmic_ in your whole project? also: Are there any other things you do to the X-Axis? I saw some posts that had several changes grouped together.. maybe there are dependencies..?